# Max. Product Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

So I was trying to solve the [Max. Product Question](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-36-cut-a-rope-to-maximize-product/) and came up with the following recursion :

```
 maxProd(n) = max of [k*(n-k),k*maxProd(n-k),maxProd(k)*(n-k),maxProd(k)*maxProd(n-k)]
```

However in the second solution given on that link they have skipped the maxProd(k)*maxProd(n-k).

```
int maxProd(int n)
{
    // Base cases
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) return 0;

    // Make a cut at different places and take the maximum of all
    int max_val = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
      max_val = max(max_val, i*(n-i), maxProd(n-i)*i);

    // Return the maximum of all values
    return max_val;
}
```

Is that still right? If so, how? Wouldn't it give wrong answers when the only way to get Max. Product is recursively split both k and n-k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you wrote here will also work. But they have a smaller one.

Note that you can get any solution from the original formula, since it checks all possible ways to choose the first cut. So if the first cut has to be i, then i will be checked, and recursively continue to the other parts.

If you use memoization, you'll get the same runtime for both formulas.